# Data structure for responding to elements as they come in?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, queue

I'm currently reviewing for my upcoming exam and I have come across a road block and can't seem to find my way around it. I need to choose between linked list, binary search tree, balanced tree, hash table, or priority queue.

What I need to do is store elements as they come in. In doing so I need to be able to respond to them in the same order in which the elements came in.

From my current knowledge of the data structures I was leaning towards a queue knowing that it takes the FIFO way of handling the elements. I am not too familiar with priority queues, but I'm thinking that would be the ideal data structure to go about in this instance. Would this be the best way to handle this situation performance wise or maybe another way?

Comment: What do you mean by "respond to them"?

Comment: @arshajii work with the elements I guess I could have said

Answer (score 2):

A priority queue isn't FIFO. It orders the elements based on a priority, whatever that may be. The only appropriate data structure you mentioned would be a linked list, as the others would reorder the elements (or be otherwise unsuitable).

Comment: thanks! Yeah because like I said I'm not too familiar with  priority queue's but seems simple enough.